# Global audio player for a website

Tags: html, drupal-7, audio-streaming, html5-audio

I am building a website on Drupal 7 and want to add an audio player on the front page, and when the user goes to another page, I want the music to remain uninterrupted (to continue playing).

Is this possible without using frames tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using javascript (more likely jQuery etc.) to load your content (via AJAX) into the page and insert it into a content block.  This will allow you to avoid frames but adds new problems.  For one you will need to change the way that most of what Drupal does for you to allow for this AJAX loading of content.  That means the menus will need to trigger javascript not load a page.  The same goes for links in the content.

With some clever jQuery you can bind much of that linking functionality with some live() events, but if you've never done that before it will be a bit tricky.  To be more specific with this I'd need to see how your code really looked.

A plugin like jQuery BBQ can take some of the pain out of this technique but it isn't going to be a magical solution, just a powerful tool so you can do it yourself. http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/